# Unable to query all history/count data with Hyperledger fabric v1.0.0 chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem in my chaincode as I am unable to query all data(past records) and display out.

What I was hoping to do was to add a counter if the same `uniqueID` variable is keyed in.

With the counter, adding with the uniqueID value i can get the right query.

Currently, I could get singular entry data from the blockchain when i ran this command:

```
peer chaincode query -C food -n food_ccv01 -c '{"Args":["queryFoodInfo","1","123456789"]}'
```

Using the `"123456789"` as a unique ID and "1" as the counter, combining them gives me a unique entry

However I am unable to use this "123456789"+counter to pull ALL data that was previously entered into the blockchain.

How can i go about this? or is there a better way?

i am not sure why my counter could not be initialized as a integer, i am using a string for now...

This is my [chaincode.](https://pastebin.com/iwKt83Rg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need to append your key with a counter, instead you can simply continue to update same key and to query for all updates since ever you can use following API:

```
// GetHistoryForKey returns a history of key values across time.
// For each historic key update, the historic value and associated
// transaction id and timestamp are returned. The timestamp is the
// timestamp provided by the client in the proposal header.
// GetHistoryForKey requires peer configuration
// core.ledger.history.enableHistoryDatabase to be true.
// The query is NOT re-executed during validation phase, phantom reads are
// not detected. That is, other committed transactions may have updated
// the key concurrently, impacting the result set, and this would not be
// detected at validation/commit time. Applications susceptible to this
// should therefore not use GetHistoryForKey as part of transactions that
// update ledger, and should limit use to read-only chaincode operations.
GetHistoryForKey(key string) (HistoryQueryIteratorInterface, error)
```

E.g. something along these lines should do a work for you:

```
func queryFoodFullInfo(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    fmt.Println("Entering Query Food information")

    // Assuming food key is at zero index
    historyIer, err := stub.GetHistoryForKey(args[0])

    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] cannot retrieve history of food record with id <%s>, due to %s", args[0], err)
        fmt.Println(errMsg)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }

    result := make([]FavouritefoodInfo, 0)
    for historyIer.HasNext() {
        modification, err := historyIer.Next()
        if err != nil {
            errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] cannot read food record modification, id <%s>, due to %s", args[0], err)
            fmt.Println(errMsg)
            return shim.Error(errMsg)
        }
        var food FavouritefoodInfo
        json.Unmarshal(modification.Value, &food)
        result = append(result, food)
    }

    outputAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(&result)                   
    return shim.Success(outputAsBytes)
 }
```

Following your initial path you probably would like to explore the [range query](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L112) capabilities:

```
// GetStateByRange returns a range iterator over a set of keys in the
// ledger. The iterator can be used to iterate over all keys
// between the startKey (inclusive) and endKey (exclusive).
// The keys are returned by the iterator in lexical order. Note
// that startKey and endKey can be empty string, which implies unbounded range
// query on start or end.
// Call Close() on the returned StateQueryIteratorInterface object when done.
// The query is re-executed during validation phase to ensure result set
// has not changed since transaction endorsement (phantom reads detected).
GetStateByRange(startKey, endKey string) (StateQueryIteratorInterface, error)
```

See [marbles example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/examples/chaincode/go/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go#L358).

Comment: Thank you! I managed to access all my past records using the GetHistoryForKey function. :) I appreciate your help greatly! Thank you!

Where can i look for more of such function in hyperleder fabric to improve my chaincode?

Comment: Had some compilation errors on `return shim.Success([]byte(json.Marshal(result))))` 
and replaced with
 
`outputAsBytes, err := json.Marshal(&result)

 return shim.Success(outputAsBytes)`

Comment: Thanks for update will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: For available API's you can take a look here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L42

Comment: The "range query" link in the answer is dead. For example, look at https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetStateByRange